# SQLAlchemy GLOB

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy over an SQLite backend and I want to perform the following sort of update:

```
UPDATE Measurement SET MeasurementCampaign=? WHERE filename GLOB ?
```

But I can't find any equivalent GLOB functionality in the SQLAlchemy docs. I have quite a few wildcard expressions and I'd really rather not rewrite them.

I've tried using the SQL directly like this:

```
session.query(Measurement).\
               filter("WHERE filename GLOB {}".format(wildcard)).update({...})
```

But I don't think that's right. Should I create a GenericFunction for "GLOB" and if so, how would I go about it?

As I say, I have many wildcards to evaluate, so if I can perform the update on them all in one go so much the better!

Comment: If an SQL function is easier to use: `a glob b` is the same as `glob(b, a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can use the ['op'](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=in_#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.PropComparator.op) function for exactly this:

```
session.query(Measurement).filter(Measurement.filename.op('GLOB')(wildcard)).update({...})
```